# Blender and Iclone 7

Tags: animation, blender-internal-render-engine

I have a problem. When i export Blender object as .fbx with goal to upload it on Iclone7 I have problems with moving materials. Before I upload model in Iclone I need to format it in 3DXChange(Iclone plug in for transforming formats)

When import my model in 3DXchange i dont get any materials. Someone has experience with this?

THanks a lot!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [.fbx export why there are no materials or textures?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures)

Comment: I used to have this problem with iClone 5 and found the texture was exporting ok, but when in iClone, I had to remap the texture.  It meant rattling through a slider in the UV toolbox until I'd get a glimpse of something on the surface of the object, and tweak it from there. It was easier to import the objects with material slots only, then apply texture in iClone.

Comment: So you are suggesting me to upload in Iclone with no materials and then do the texture inside Iclone? What means import object with MATERIAL SLOTS? and one more question can I make multiple materials on one object(Character) in Iclone?